# MySQL Many for Many table: getting number of results

Tags: mysql

I have a database of three tables: `USERS` `PHOTOS` `LIKES` and a basic outline would be like so:

```
USERS:
user_id
name


PHOTOS:
photo_id
title
url
user_id

LIKES:
user_id
photo_id
```

What I want to do is enable a user to like many photos and have photos liked by many users.

Obviously, I want to order these photos by the number of likes, which I can do with a `JOIN` and `COUNT()`

What I need to do which I can't figure out is return the number of 'likes' which each photo has. How would I do this?

my current SQL is:

```
SELECT 
  photos.photo_id,
  photos.title,
  photos.url,
  users.name
FROM photos
LEFT OUTER JOIN users
ON users.user_id = photos.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes
ON likes.photo_id = photos.photo_id
GROUP BY likes.photo_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Just add `COUNT(*)` to your select list?

Comment: *facepalm* It's been one of those days... you should probably post that as the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `COUNT(*)` to your select list:

```
SELECT 
  photos.photo_id,
  photos.title,
  photos.url,
  users.name,
  COUNT(*)
FROM photos
LEFT OUTER JOIN users
ON users.user_id = photos.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes
ON likes.photo_id = photos.photo_id
GROUP BY likes.photo_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: although there is a slight error, it was my error from the post and thus I'll fix it in my post and fix it in this answer for you, too!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT 
    photos.photo_id,
    photos.title,
    photos.url,
    users.name, 
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT 
FROM photos, users 
WHERE users.user_id = photos.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes
ON likes.photo_id = photos.photo_id
GROUP BY likes.photo_id ORDER BY COUNT(likes.photo_id) DESC
```